# A synonym for "moral hypocrite"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, pejorative-language

I'm looking for a precise word to describe someone who is hypocritical on moral issues,
for example:

- a cult guru who claims to be holy while doing something evil.
- or a company which partakes in some kind of sordid business practice while pretending to be holier-than-thou.

Comment: What's wrong with _hypocrite_?

Comment: I agree with @terdon. In fact, I'd argue that most hypocrisy *is* moral hypocrisy, and it seems [many dictionaries](http://www.onelook.com/?w=hypocrisy&ls=a) would support that assertion.

Comment: That is precisely the meaning of hypocrisy. Searching for _moral_ hypocrisy is like searching for wet water.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the word is ***sanctimonious*** defined in the dictionary as

> making a hypocritical show of religious devotion, piety, righteousness, etc.: *They resented his sanctimonious comments on immorality in America.*

Answer (score 1):

The [thesaurus](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hypocrite) provides us with

> - pharisee
> - Tartuffe
> - Holy Willie
> - whited sepulchre
> - phoney or phony
> - beguiler
> - cheater
> - deceiver
> - slicker
> - cheat
> - fraud
> - deceiver
> - pretender
> - charlatan
> - impostor